# Android oboe library clicks at the start / end of a sound

Tags: android, oboe

I'm using [oboe](https://github.com/google/oboe) library in my app to generate sound. Their example [SineGenerator](https://github.com/google/oboe/blob/master/samples/hello-oboe/src/main/cpp/SineGenerator.cpp) is pretty much exactly what I need, just a simple sine wave that generates a frequency that I need. This generated sine wave is later user in the [PlayAudioEngine](https://github.com/google/oboe/blob/master/samples/hello-oboe/src/main/cpp/PlayAudioEngine.cpp#L184).

The problem is that more often than not, there's a clicking sound at the beginning or at the end of the audio I play. I play the sounds in short consecutive bursts, usually between 50 - 150ms in length.

I don't really have experience in generating audio waves, so maybe this is just me not seeing something very obvious. I've tried optimizing the performance (compiler flags + code) as suggested in [this article](https://medium.com/@donturner/debugging-audio-glitches-on-android-ed10782f9c64) but that yielded no results. I've also tried ramping down the amplitude, but no noticeable results.

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Problems like this are usually due to a phase discontinuity that causes a sharp jump in amplitude, from 0 to `sinf(mPhase) * mAmplitude`. For example, if you reset `mPhase` to 0 before attempting to render the sound, that'll get rid of the click at the start. Then you just have a find a way to _end_ the wave at a phase of 0.

Answer (score 1):

A click when starting the oscillator is caused by not resetting the phase in `Oscillator::setWaveOn(true)` (as mentioned by @greeble31 in comments). It's a simple fix for the "wave on" scenario, just set `mPhase` to zero.

For "wave off" a solution would be to have a very short ramp down in amplitude rather than just cutting the sound off.

You *could* do this in `Oscillator::renderAudio`, however, it'd probably be more flexible to implement a separate `Envelope` class which can handle the ramp down independently.

Comment: To be fair, this issue could be classed as bug in the samples so if you file an issue (https://github.com/google/oboe/issues/new) I'll try to add an `Envelope` class which would fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I didn't have time to try and implement this solution, but will look into this. Thanks again!